# Returning a list in each iteration using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have an object which contains one value and a list. Now I have a list of those objects and want to concatenate all values and lists into one large list.

This is my current state:

```
class Language:
    def __init__(self, name, code, *args):
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        self.alt = args
language_list = [Language("Deutsch", "deu", "de", "ger"), 
                 Language("Español", "spa", "es"), 
                 Language("English", "eng", "en"), 
                 Language("Svenska", "swe", "sv"), 
                 Language("Dansk", "dan", "da"), 
                 Language("ﺎﻠﻠﻏﺓ ﺎﻠﻋﺮﺒﻳﺓ", "ara", "ar"), 
                 Language("Italiano", "ita", "it"), 
                 Language("Français", "fra", "fr")]

print([[ lang.code ] + list(lang.alt) for lang in languages_list])
```

This would return a two dimensional array:

```
[["deu", "de", "ger"], ["spa", "es"], ["eng", "en"]…
```

Now is there a way, to either merge that into one large list, or that it basically does `[].extend()` instead of `[].append()` on each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you either have to flatten like this

```
print([item for lang in languages_list for item in [lang.code] + list(lang.alt)])
```

Or

```
from itertools import chain
print([item for lang in languages_list for item in chain([lang.code], lang.alt)])
```

I would prefer the `itertools.chain` method, since it doesn't have to create a long list, incase your `lang.alt` is long.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, you have to write a for-loop:

```
langs = []
for lang in languages_list:
    langs.append(lang.code)
    langs.extend(lang.alt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OOP way to achieve this is to define a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method for your class:

```
class Language(object):

    def __init__(self, name, code, *args):
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        self.alt = args

    def __str__(self):
        return str(list(tuple([self.code]) + self.alt))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(list(tuple([self.code]) + self.alt))
```

This yields:

```
>>> print Language("Deutsch", "deu", "de", "ger")
['deu', 'de', 'ger']
```

You can then build on this with a `LanguageList` class:

```
class LanguageList(list):

    def __str__(self):
        return str([i for i in self])
```

Demo:

```
>>> language_list = LanguageList([Language("Deutsch", "deu", "de", "ger"), 
                                  Language("Español", "spa", "es"), 
                                  Language("English", "eng", "en"), 
                                  Language("Svenska", "swe", "sv")])

>>> print language_list
[['deu', 'de', 'ger'], ['spa', 'es'], ['eng', 'en'], ['swe', 'sv']]
```